# Azure pipeline API call gate success criteria evaluation

Tags: json, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In my azure pipeline I have a post release gate that I want to call my API to make sure it was deployed and is returning values that I expect.
I have added the service connection and am able to get a response from the API, but I am unsure how to evaluate the response, which is just an array of values :

```
["ACURA","ALFA ROMEO","AUDI","BMW","BUICK"]
```

How to I first check that the call was successful, and secondly check the existence of "AUDI" in the return values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could add a new stage which under your current stage.

When you current stage's **Deployment Gate** uses [Invoke REST API task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) to response the values, as long as the new stage runs, the API call is sure to have succeeded.
To check the value, use Postman to get the returned values of the api.

Comment: I already have this. I am just struggling to validate what is returned (the above array of strings).